How many times does $E=mc^2$ appear in Stephen Hawking's book A Brief History of Time?
How many times does $E=mc^2$ appear in Stephen Hawking's book A Brief History of Time? In the preface, he stated that no other equations would be included in the book, but how many times is this equation actually used? Could someone count them?

This book is not particularly obscure. Surely a nearby public or college library has a copy for you to look at. Or even a bookstore, as copies are still fairly often found in used bookstores. There almost always are several copies at a nearby bookstore I visit every few weeks. And yes, I have a copy (obtained a month or two after it first appeared), but counting appearances of $E=mc^2$ in the book is not something I consider worth spending several minutes doing.

There almost always are several copies at a nearby bookstore --- It just so happens I was there yesterday (wasn't planning to when I wrote my earlier note, but decided to stop in since I happened to be in Cedar Rapids for other reasons and hadn't been to the store in 6-7 weeks) and there were $5$ copies on the shelves (all paperbacks more recently printed than my first edition hardback, however). It wasn't until I was looking over the math and physical science books and saw copies of it that I remembered your question, and so I counted the number of copies on the shelves.

Three times (in chapters 2, 7, and 11).

THX! I appreciate your help.
